# Generate random cycle that approximates a given weight

Tags: graph, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, cycle

Is there a graph algorithm for solving the following problem:

Given a weighted undirected graph `G` (all weights are positive), a start node `N` and a total weight `W*`. Generate a random cycle through the graph, starting and ending at node `N`, of which the total weight (the summed weight of all the edges) approximates the given weight `W*`.

One could see this as generating *the* cycle that *best* approximates `W*`, but generating *a* cycle that approximates `W*` within some margin of error is also fine.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a simple cycle, you want an approximation algorithm for the travelling salesman problem.  I believe there are known hardness results, indicating that this is NP-hard for general graphs, but there is a wide range of heuristics; you can check the literature.